# Updating multi-dimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays, shell, multidimensional-array

I have the following defined in C:

```
#define MAX_COMMANDS 10;
char * commandHistory[MAX_COMMANDS][MAX_LENGTH + 1];
```

The idea is to keep track of the last 10 commands entered on my custom shell. I only want to keep track of the 10 most recent commands. Each command needs to be associated with a number, 1,2,3,4, etc, so I can later be able to use !83 (for example) to re-execute the the 83rd entered command.

So, I am fine up until the point that my command history looks like this:

```
commandHistory = [cmd0, cmd1, cmd2, ... , cmd9]
```

I also have a variable I am using to index, i, that will be at 10 when the next command is entered

At this point I am perfectly fine. What do I do when the next cmd is entered on the shell. I need the commandHistory to look like this:

```
commandHistory = [cmd1, cmd2, cmd3, ... , cmd10]
```

but I also need to be able to print their commands + number, so the 10th entered command would print out as 10  cmd10. I also need to be able to later on call !10 from my shell and execute that command (this is if the given command is one of the 10 remembered still).

I need help because I am not sure how to tackle this. Thanks

Comment: commandHistory, as defined, creates a 2 dimensional array of pointers to characters (well, technically it does something else, but socially that is what it does).  I assume that MAX_LENGTH is the length of a line and you want to store MAX_COMMANDS lines.  Thus, you should not be storing `char*`s in those elements, but rather `char`s.  If you were doing dynamic allocation, you would remove the second array and leave the char*s.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use an array of pointers and track the dynamic memory.  Reduces memory use and makes having items fall off the end more straightforward.

Obviously untested, and I didn't study this carefully to make sure I didn't have an off by one error or something, but the general concept should be pretty clear.

```
char commandHistory[MAX_COMMANDS][MAX_LENGTH+1];
int histSize = 0;
int histBase = 0;

void addHistory(const char *cmd)
{
  if (++histSize >= MAX_COMMANDS)
  {
    for(int x=1;x<MAX_COMMANDS;x++)
     memcpy(commandHistory[x-1],commandHistory[x],(MAX_LENGTH+1));
    histSize--;
    histBase++;
  }
  memcpy(commandHistory[histSize],cmd,MIN(strlen(cmd),MAX_LENGTH));
}
char *gethistory(int num)
{
   int offset = num - histBase;
   if (offset < 0 || offset > histSize)
     return(NULL);
   return(commandHistory[offset]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the commands always have an associated number, the representation which seems most natural (to me) is a struct.

```
struct {
    int num;
    char *cmd;
};
```

Then there's choice of how to represent a sequence of these. You could make a linked-list.

```
struct cmd {
    int num;
    char *cmd;
    struct cmd *next;
} *head = NULL;
```

Or an array.

```
struct {
    int num;
    char *cmd;
} cmdhist[MAX_CMD_HIST];
```

Once you fill up, you can loop back through the same array and update from 0 to MAX again. And now you have the associated number tracked together with its command string.

And of course, all the `char *cmd;` lines could be `char cmd[MAX_CMD_LENGTH]` if you really want fixed arrays. They work just fine wrapped in a struct.

```
for (int i=0; i<MAX_CMD_HIST; i++)
    if (cmdnum == cmdhist[i].num)
         return /*execute cmdhist[i].cmd*/;
return /*not found*/;
```